# Fire Angularjs event when tab/browser is closed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, dom-events, angular-ui

I would like to fire JS code in Angularjs controller.

I have this:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
            alert('page1');
        });
```

This is working fine when I'm navigating away from the page which is using that controller but its not working when I'm closing tab/browser.

Do I need to use some other code to fire JS code when tab/browser is closing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the angular docs:

> **$destroy();**
>
> Removes the current scope (and all of its children) from
>   the parent scope. Removal implies that calls to $digest() will no
>   longer propagate to the current scope and its children. Removal also
>   implies that the current scope is eligible for garbage collection.
>
> The $destroy() is usually used by directives such as ngRepeat for
>   managing the unrolling of the loop.
>
> Just before a scope is destroyed, a $destroy event is broadcasted on
>   this scope. Application code can register a $destroy event handler
>   that will give it a chance to perform any necessary cleanup.
>
> Note that, in AngularJS, there is also a $destroy jQuery event, which
>   can be used to clean up DOM bindings before an element is removed from
>   the DOM.

This just handles the situation where the scope itself is being destroyed, that does not seem to occur when the tab/browser is closed though.

You will have to use lower level methods onunload and onbeforeunload events to handle this situation, here is another post you may find useful:

[javascript detect browser close tab/close browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser)